# Change font size for entire gt() table in quarto with Latex / PDF output?

Tags: r, quarto, gt

I am creating a document with Quarto and want to change the font size of my tables made with the gt() package.
While this works fine for HTML output, it has no effect for PDF output.
Does anyone know a solution?

````
---
format: pdf
---

```{r}
library(gt)
gt(mtcars) |> tab_options(table.font.size = 7)
```
```{r}
gt(mtcars) |> tab_options(table.font.size = 12)
```
````

Comment: Maybe try adding `quarto.use_bootstrap = TRUE` argument to the `tab_options()` function?

Comment: Or, additionally, you could try adding `quarto.disable_processing = TRUE` to `tab_options()` instead. Both my suggestions can from reading the [function documentation](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/tab_options.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Quinton.Quagliano but both do not have any effect in the PDF.

Comment: It looks like there are some known deficits when exporting gt to PDF, see this [github discussion](https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/1363) and the other links within.

Comment: I find that the `kableExtra` package has had some good success for me exporting PDF tables, if you wanted to explore that

Comment: Thanks for the additional link and info. I have been using `kableExtra` before and like it but I wanted to switch to something which can do both Latex and Word and arrived at the `gt` package. It has been working well as a replacement, the only thing I couldn't get right so far is the font size.

Comment: you could use `gt::as_latex` and add `\tiny` inside the table.

Comment: Thanks, @Julian. This does it as a workaround. Basically, using `\scriptsize` before the table and `\normalsize` afterwards.

Comment: Glad that it works for you and hopefully it will get fixed soon :)